# Must not allow sharing files and document

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

Lot of files and document downloaded from web server and saved into NSDocumentDirectory.

Mobile applications must not allow sharing of its files and documents with unapproved mobile applications on the same mobile device?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior on iOS for native apps due to sandboxing.